# How to avoid my filters to cause "another operation in progress" error in Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird, email-client

I have two incoming mail boxes that I read with [thunderbird](/questions/tagged/thunderbird). On both I have filters. Now it happens very often that when I've got mails in both mail boxes, I get the below error message:

> The messages could not be filtered to folder 'Inbox' because another operation is in progress.

Is there a way to check one mail box after the other, which should prevent me from getting this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I am not going to move to another software because I'm very happy with Thunderbird.

And after a little thinking, I went and Edited ***Account Settings*** (not preferences, what did mislead me from the beginning) and changed  the ***Server Settings*** for the accounts.

- instead of having both being checked at start, I have now the main one being checked at start;
- then in case I forget to do a ***manual Get Message*** (top left hand corner), I have the other account checked after 3 minutes.

[image: Thunderbird Account Settings]

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a limitation of the mbox format that firefox uses (with a slight tweak) as they are one file per mailbox and assume a single thread of access not multiple ones. Try converting your mailbox to another of the supported formats like Maildir , Mork or MozStorage which can better handle concurrent accesses.

Be sure to back up your mail box first and to test the other formats before relying on them.